# Does adding Dynatrace Headers in LoadRunner adds up Response time?

Tags: performance, testing, load-testing, loadrunner, dynatrace

I have around 150 requests in my LoadRunner HTTP/HTML protocol. I have added 150 tagged web requests (dynatrace headers).

I experimented executing the script with dynatrace headers and without dynatrace headers. Each time, I am getting different response time.

I am just curious to know dynatrace headers will add up or impact the response in the results.

Comment: If you have executed the test runs correctly then you are the one who can share the insights.

Comment: I just want to confirm :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should not impact your response time largely and as far I have seen DT gives you a trustworthy response time. The DT response time should be consistent unless your AUT is unstable and already into non performing mode.

You should be able to correlate this by executing couple of tests with LR and DT+ LR and compare.

If you have a habit of looking at server logs then that should be the best place to confirm the behavior as well.

Also double check your scripts once you have added DT headers , if you haven't placed your Transactional timers properly that can impact your analysis as well.

Answer (score 0):

Between two executions, an AUT should give you very similar results unless any changes pertaining to load injection patterns, regardless of your DT.

However, if you are comparing the load runner result (transaction response times provided by Load runner )along with DT based transaction names, I have seen DT tend to provide a much less value in comparison to what LR provides.This is due to the fact that LR takes the response time E2E .Were as DT it depends upon how much instrumentation you have in place